# IE7 CSS for IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to design my disabled select box in IE7.

```
<div id="wwctrl_pay" class="wwctrl styled-select">
     <select id="payment"><option>...</option></select>
</div>
```

How can I change the CSS of `#wwctrl_pay` if the select box is disabled?
Can I do it using CSS?

Comment: how / when you are disabling the select box?

Comment: are you doing this in code behind(server side) or in client side using  javascript or jquery, From the code above it seems like javascript or jquery

Comment: @MusikAnimal: Just for comedy's sake: uppercase tags and unquoted attributes are valid HTML... but not a `<select>` without any `<options>` :P I did mark your edit helpful of course ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind some extra markup, and other limitations:

http://jsfiddle.net/s6LbB/1/

```
<div id="wwctrl_pay" class="wwctrl styled-select">
     <select id="payment" disabled="disabled"></select>
     <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wwctrl {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

select[disabled] + div {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
​
```

Alternatively, if this is for IE7 only, you could try using IE's proprietary css expressions feature.

Comment: I'm on a mac, so trying on IE is highly uncomfy, but in theory it should. Try the fiddle yourself.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal: they are working a bit in IE7: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector . In IE6 they are  not, but who gives a $#!t.

Answer (score 2):

Best option is when you disable the select box, Add a new class and add your style within that class.